# How to determine that X source code can be reliably compiled into Y binary (for various platforms)

Tags: java, c++, .net, audit

We're taking over the source code from some vendors who had maintained the source code for a long time (for better or for worse). One of the things we need to verify is whether the version of the source code that they handover to us really matches to the version compiled and deployed into production currently. The question is, how to do this in a non-intrusive way (i.e. I don't want to compile and throw it into production to see if something breaks).

I know that it's not possible to compile the same source code into identical JARs and DLLs over different periods of time as there will be different metadata  packaged into the JARs and DLLs which would make a simple checksum match impossible. However, is there another way to be able to verify that the source code does in fact compile into what's in production? For e.g. in Java, can we unzip the JAR file and compare the *.class files instead and determine the accuracy from there?

Thanks!
Wong

Comment: It's actually impossible to say that source X will always generate binary Y, [who says that the compiler can be trusted](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwi56Pe-xOnIAhVHlCwKHSC5A0A&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ece.cmu.edu%2F~ganger%2F712.fall02%2Fpapers%2Fp761-thompson.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGvvB_T31mu1wdo7SuVZrAfl_1klw&sig2=NZKBqcjMSGrW_fEmxxP2hg) (warning: PDF link).